# Where does the Devi Bhagavata Mahapurana state that it is the best among the 18 main Puranas?

Tags: puranas, vyasa, devi

The importance of the Devi Bhagavata Mahapurana can be ascertained from the following two passages:

> The Srimad Devi Bhagavatam, also known as Devi Purana, was composed
>   into 12 chapters, containing 18000 verses by the great Veda Vyasa.
>   Though classified as an upa-purana **it is the only purana Vedavyasa
>   called “Maha Purana” meaning the great purana.** At the end of each
>   chapter of the 18 main puranas or the upa puranas is the verse “This
>   is the end of the fifth section of the Vishnu Purana”, or “Thus ends
>   the first chapter of Ganesha Purana Upasanakhanda called “The
>   Description of Somakanta”. Where as in the Devi Bhagavatam it is
>   clearly – “Thus ends the eighth chapter of the first Skandha in the
>   Mahapurâna Srimad Devî Bhâgavatam of 18,000 verses by Maharsi
>   Vedavyâsa”

Source-[Astrojyoti.com(Translation of Devi Purana by Swami Vijyananda)](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatamindex.htm)

> The unfolding  of  the subject matter was  that of Devi Bhagavata
>   Purana, **originally recited by Krishna Dvaipayana Maharshi Veda Vyasa,
>   who described it as Maha Purana, elevating its status above the
>   Eighteen Main Puranas,** viz. Agni Purana, Bhagavata Purana, Bhavishya
>   Purana, Brahma Purana, Brahmanda Purana, Brahma  Vivarta Purana,
>   Garuda Purana, Kurma Purana, Linga Purana, Matysa Purana, Markandeya
>   Purana, Narada Purana, Padma Purana, Skanda Purana, Siva Purana,
>   Vamana Purana, Varaha Purana, and Vishnu Purana.

Source-[The preface of the book "Essence of the Devi Bhagvatam" hosted by Kamakoti.org.](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/devibhagvatpurana1.html)

**My Question**-**Is it explicitly stated in Devi Bhagvata Mahapurna itself that it is the best among the 18 main Puranas?If so where?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes,the Devi Bhagavata itself states that it is the best among the 18 main Puranas.It is so stated in the first chapter of the Purana.**

The following is a screenshot of the page that contains the relevant verses.And here the relevant verses are the **17th,18th** and the **23rd** ones.

[image]

Transliterations and translations of the 3 verses are as follows:

> *Ashtaadasha puraanaani sa kritavaa Bhagavaan Munih maamevaadhyaapayaamaasu bhaarataakhyaana evacha(17)|| **Devibhagavatam
>   tatra puraanam bhogamokshadam, swayam tu shraavayaamaat Janamejaya
>   bhushitam(18)**||-----**Ashaadasha puraanaam madhye sarvottamam param,
>   Devi Bhagavatam** naama dharmaartha kaamaartha mokshadam (23)||*

Translation-

> Maharshi Vyasa scripted the Eighteen Puranas about the Oriental
>   Bhaarata Desha yet Devi Bhagavata Purana aims at achievement of Moksha
>   as strongly opined by Emperor Janamejaya.(17 & 18)
>
> **Among the eighteen puranas, Devi Bhagavata is the best(sarvottamam
>   param)& it stands out shining as the accomplisher of  Four
>   Purushardhas of Dharma-Artha-Kaama-Mokshas**(23)